# Are there negative effects for wasting time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, you can sleep or wait for up to a day at a time. Is there any negative consequences to wasting time like this? Do certain quests expire or certain conditions happen after several days (or even weeks) have passed that can be considered negative?

Obviously temporary buffs expire, but that happens after one day.

Comment: How do you wait on 360? I can't seem to find the button or cue to just wait?

Comment: @Amanda Press the back button, to the left of the (X) button in the middle of the controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing negative happens if you wait for a long time. Anything you have killed (dungeons, guards, etc.) will re-spawn and shop keepers will get new stock. Quest will not expire at any point so you are safe to wait for as long as you like.

Comment: [Sleeping](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping) will also give you the well rested bonus for 8 hours which is a 10% bonus to skill increases.